# Rendering 3D model in XNA and show me this error, 65535 primitives per draw call, but this ModelMeshPart contains 216896 triangles

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, xna, xna-4.0

Hi I'm trying to display a 3D model of Dress in (**.fbx**) format in **XNA** using Microsoft Visual studio express 2012  but it show me this error.

> **XNA** Framework Reach profile supports a maximum of **65535** primitives per draw call, but this ModelMeshPart contains **216896**
>   triangles. Reduce the number of triangles, or split the model into
>   several smaller meshes.

Someone know what i need to change to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

By default in many 3D API, indexed triangle meshes use 16 bit unsigned index values, thus allowing for only 65536 verticies (primitives).. It is possible with some 3D API to use 32 bit index values.

According to some quick research on the XNA Framework Reach Profile, 32 bit index values are NOT supported... you will have to select a different profile (if there is one that supports 32 bit indexes), or you will have to split your mesh up into smaller pieces rendered separatly... If you are stuck with the Reach profile for other reasons, mesh splitting is your only choice.

Since you have the source artwork (.fbx), you will probably want to do the splitting in your modeling software... all the sub-meshes should still work with the same shaders and textures as long as you keep the UV coordinates unchanged from the original mesh to the split mesh

Answer (score 0):

XNA Framework comes with 2 profiles, Reach and Hi-Def.
You can change the profile under the project properties. (It should be the first thing you see)
To open the properties for your project, right-click it in project explorer and click properties.